# How to close Modal Dialog after clicking save button? SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

I have created an aspx page and I have created 1 custom save button and 1 cancel button :

```
<input type="button" id="savebutton" value="Apply for Vacancy" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')};" />

<input type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" onclick="javascript: window.frameElement.commitPopup();" />
```

After I click the cancel button the dialog is being closed, but when I click `Save` button the dialog is not closing.

I have tried this code for saving button:

```
onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}; window.frameElement.commitPopup();"
```

It works in internet explorer but in chrome it is not working. so how can I made this to work in both browsers.

DIALOG FUNCTION

```
 function openDialog(idja) {
                var options = {

                    url: 'http://mysite/sites/stonehr/Lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=' + idja,
                    title: 'mylist',
                    allowMaximize: true,
                    showClose: true,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 900
                };
                SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);

            }
```

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting in chrome?? f12 and get the generated output

Comment: the error is that it is not saving the item

Comment: so on chrome its not outputting any error?

Comment: no there is not any error output

Comment: do you know what method your using or is used to create the popup?

Comment: yes you can see it in updated question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46748/discussion-between-nderon-hyseni-and-ali-jafer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the form is saving just need to redirect:

do the following on save button:

```
javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirectsource;')}
```

Comment: no problem happy to help